# swfobject variable from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flash, variables

I have several variables which i use to call flash movie, but i dont want to include that on document.ready because first i need one variable from jquery ajax response.

```
 var flashvars = {
                "debug.enabled":"true",
                "background": "#000",
                "uploadUrl": "UploadImage.ashx?id=" + var_from_ajax}
```

I have defined var_from_ajax outside document.ready.

My Ajax success function is

```
success: function(data) { var_from_ajax = data.id; swfobject.embedSWF("movie.swf", "divID", "600", "400", "10.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);}
```

But looks like i cannon embed my movie with variable from ajax request.. any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create `flashvars.uploadURL`, it is simply "UploadImage.ashx?id=" plus whatever `var_from_ajax` is at that time. After `flashvars.uploadURL` is set, `var_from_ajax` is never referenced. Try this:

```
success: function(data) {
    flashvars.uploadUrl = "UploadImage.ashx?id=" + data.id;
    swfobject.embedSWF("movie.swf", "divID", "600", "400", "10.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
}
```